# Google Calendar API without Google play services

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-source

This is my first question, so I hope I am asking this right.

I am trying to find a way to access Google Calendar information for an android app.  The device that is going to run this app does not allow Google Play Services.

The device runs on AOSP with no Google Services.

I have done a few weeks of research and I can not find my answer.  I have looked into Google Calendar Provider, Google Calendar API, and Google Calendar GData API. I actually wrote the app with Google Calendar Provider before I knew that the device would not allow it.

If someone could point me into the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: for google calendar we don't require any services we can directly use by using permissins like read calendar write calendar just check once

Comment: @Allu - without Google Play Services, there won't be a Google Calendar app and therefore no Google Calendar information in the CalendarProvider

Comment: what you want from calendar

Comment: The only way that comes to mind is sending hand-crafted JSON requests to the calendar API but authentication will likely be tricky..

Comment: @Allu I need to read and write to the calendar.  It looks like I will need to do it RESTful style, but getting the authentication is going to be hard.

Comment: I would like to sync data to google from my calendar app. Did you get any way to do that ? @CaptainMorgan

Comment: Do you still need it ? I may have an answer.